# Detecting if user is uploading the same image

Tags: php, ajax, image, mysqli

I have a form that contains an image upload and an input text box. The user will be able to upload an image and enter text without refreshing the page using Ajax. The image will be relayed to PHP and PHP will handle what to do with the image. My problem is that for the first time the user uploads an image, it'll be checked if the same image name is on the server or not. If it is, the image name will get a uniqid() and then will be uploaded. But what if the user changes the data in the text box field, but keeps the image? Then that image will be uploaded again with a uniqid() since it's already on the server. I've tried solving this using my current code for the image handling:

**PHP**

```
$target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/stories/media/images/$name";
        if (isset($_SESSION["size"]))
        {
            $prevSize = $_SESSION["size"];

            if (filesize($prevSize) != filesize($size))
            {
                if (@getimagesize($target_file) == true)
                {
                    $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);     
                    $name = basename($name, "." . $ext);
                    $name = $name . uniqid() . "." . $ext;
                    $target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/stories/media/images/$name";
                }
            }

        }

        else
        {
            $_SESSION["size"] = $size;

            if (@getimagesize($target_file) == true)
            {
                $ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);     
                $name = basename($name, "." . $ext);
                $name = $name . uniqid() . "." . $ext;
                $target_file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/stories/media/images/$name";
            }
        }




        move_uploaded_file($tempName, $target_file);
```

Unfortunately, this code isn't working like I want it to. If I upload the same image twice in a row, in the same session, it doesn't override my previous image. Instead, it puts it on the server with a uniqid name. What am I doing wrong? And if there's a better way in solving this, I'd love to know!

Comment: instead of generating a unique id, how about using a hash like md5? this would make it easy to detect duplicates: hash the image that was uploaded, check if filename matching the hash exists, if it exists, use that file, otherwise save the image with the hash as the filename

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is whenever someone uploads an image,  store a hash of the image, encrypt it and store it in the database on the image row. 
From now on,  whenever someone uploads an image run a query like this:
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM images WHERE hash = $hash` then in an if statement check if the returned value is bigger than 0, if it is,  do what you need to do without re-uploading the image,  and if it is 0, then upload your image and proceed

Comment: What if someone uploads a different image, but with the same name?

Comment: Hashing something like an image,  as long as you use the same algorithm will return the exact same hash,  regardless of name etc... This way you can compare images to see if they are the Exact same, the only drawback is that you won't be able to detect different resolutions and filters or gamma settings and the like. To do that you'd need an ai that can intelligently compare images.

Comment: How would I implement the hash? Is the stored database hash an image with random characters or just random characters?

Comment: I don't think you need any encryption here, nor a strong cryptographic hash function, so something as simple as `$hash = md5_file($uploadedFilename);` should do the trick.

Comment: @Arnauld `md5_file()` means you are hashing the file using the md5 encryption algorithm. And @user2896120 the value the hash function Arnauld mentioned returns a string of characters,  which you can store in a column on the image table

Answer (score 0):

I chose a user avatar upload for this example. I'm not sure what your image is, but the workflow should be similar. No duplicate avatars will be copied to the image path.

```
function get_avatar_filename($filename) {
  // only generate an avatar filename if the mimetype matches
  switch (mime_content_type($filename)) {
    case 'image/jpeg':
      return sprintf('%s.jpg', hash_file('md5', $filename));
    case 'image/gif':
      return sprintf('%s.gif', hash_file('md5', $filename));
    case 'image/png':
      return sprintf('%s.png', hash_file('md5', $filename));

    // otherwise the user uploaded a non-supported image
    // return the default image
    default:
      return 'default-avatar.jpg';
  }
}

function upload_avatar($avatarPath, $filename) {
  // get the avatar filename
  $f = get_avatar_filename($filename);

  // copy the file to $avarPath only if the file doesn't already exist
  if (!file_exists("{$avatarPath}/{$f}")) {
    move_uploaded_file($filename, "{$avatarPath}/{$f}");
  }

  // return the avatar filename
  return $f;
}
```

Now you can use these functions when you process the user form submission

```
// process user form submission ...
// ...

$filename = upload_avatar(
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/stories/media/images/",
  $_FILES['user_avatar']['tmp_name']
);

// save the avatar location for the user ...
// or whatever
$user->setAvatar($filename);
$user->save();
```

If the user uploads a non-supported image type, they will just be assigned `default-avatar.jpg` which is a file that should exist in your images directory.